# externally connect to my stellar node

Tags: stellar-core, nodes

I created a private stellar node on my server using the documentation. When I am trying to externally connect to my node using curl I get the following error on stellar-core:

> [Overlay ERROR] TCP: message size unacceptable: 1195725856 while not authenticated [TCPPeer.cpp:360]

The curl error I get:

> cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Could you help me with this, maybe configuration missing from my side?